# api showing context of words in sentences

Tags: api, machine-learning, nlp, speech

Hello I am curious about API's for determining the context of words in sentences

Ever since I saw the emergence of sentiment aggregators - scripts which tried to assess the sentiment of a sentence - I have been wondering about more complex versions of this. Basically the sentiment aggragators I saw are actually very simple, they just try to assign a positive and negative value to a sentence, but still do not know the context. Similarly I have been disappointed by the current progress of machines detecting context

I was thinking a more complex algorithm would assign many more attributes to a word and compare them to other words

example:

`The quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog.`

the word fox would be interpreted as an object

```
{
    word: fox,
    type: noun,
    relation: ...
}
```

where it now knows that fox is referring to the mammal, and not the verb "to baffle of deceive", for instance, and this would be useful for translating into another language or judging a good response for a robot

are there any good APIs for this, or open source projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For advanced sentiment analysis, one possible step is to find the word sense of each word and the dependencies between the words. There is a lot that you can do Once you have that information. For example, you can handle negations, smooth the senses using parenting (broader concept), etc. You can also go beyond the simple like/dislike to identify targetted intents or topics (e.g., violence, illegal activities, etc). The ability to properly detect the sense of the word eliminates much of the noise. (For example the word "like" does not convey sentiment in "Like others, I've ...".)

Answer (score 2):

Never delved into NLP much, but sounds like a "parts-of-speech tagger" could get you whether a word is a noun or verb in a particular context.  This one worked for your sentence, at least. http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/pos/?id=4

Answer (score 0):

Words have some meanings individually and they have different meanings at difference sentences as you mentioned. Let's assume that a word has a list of meanings. When translating a word from one language to another language that words meaning can be predicted as which meaning in that list has highest probability to become at that sentence (has a higher probability to become with other words at given sentence)

Such kind of situations can be solved by HMMs at Machine Learning. You can read that [blog post](http://blogs.cornell.edu/info2040/2012/11/11/hidden-markov-models-and-text-translation/) about Hidden Markov Models and Text Translation from Cornell University's web site.

You should look at that kind of APIs. Stanford University has a Java NLP Api and you should look at here: http://dbpubs.stanford.edu:8091/~klein/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/hmm/package-tree.html